# Variable showing as 'undefined' when I try to hit the route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I thought I had properly set up my CRUD for two different models (venues & artists) -- venues works fine but when I try to hit my 'artists/index', I receive the error 'Artists is not defined'.

As far as I can tell, I only need two things:

1. Artist variable defined (7th row from top)
2. A get request in the app.js (route syntax is listed in the very last grouping below)

I've confirmed my post requests work by validating there's artist data in the database using the terminal, but I can't get them to pull through the route.

Can you help me understand what I'm missing? It's driving me nuts!

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const Venue = require('./models/venue');
const Artist = require('./models/artist');

const dbUrl = process.env.DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/data-base';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Database connected");
});

const app = express();

app.engine('ejs', ejsMate);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home')
})

app.get('/venues', async (req, res) => {
    const venues = await Venue.find({});
    res.render('venues/index', { venues })
});

app.get('/artists', async (req, res) => {
    const artists = await Artist.find({});
    res.render('artists/index', { artists })
});
```

I'm receiving the following error and you can see artists/index.ejs on my [github](https://github.com/chaseschlachter/musicmaker/blob/main/index.ejs)

```
ReferenceError: /Users/chaseschlachter/mtapp/views/artists/index.ejs:8
<ul>
 <%  for (let artist of Artists) {%>
  <li><a href="/artists/<%= artist._id %>"><%= artist.name %>/a></li>
     <% } %> 
 </ul>

Artists is not defined
```

Comment: const artists = await Artist.find({});
res.render('artists/index') -> didn't you forget to pass the artists var to the template?

Comment: Please include the *exact* error, in its context. There is no `artist/index` afaict so assuming that's a typo. You don't pass `artists` in to whatever you're rendering, which seems like a potential problem.

Comment: @RaniSharim good call - I added the syntax but am still receiving the error.

Comment: @DaveNewton apologies - below is a link to the artists/index.ejs in my github. I added the full error to the question above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @econobro But what I meant by "there is no `artist/index`" was that it doesn't align with your code, which is `artists/index`.

Comment: Try changing the template to use lowercase artists, and passing { artists } to the render function

Comment: @DaveNewton I see what you're saying. Thanks for pointing that out (tough to answer when I'm making typos). I've updated the original question to align with the code.

Comment: @RaniSharim that worked!!! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you missed to include `artists` in `res.render('artists/index', artists )`.

As you need to specify in more detail your codebase.

Comment: Apologies - here's a link to my index.ejs. (it's in folder 'views' -> 'artists' - index.ejs). Somewhat new with github so let me know if you're able to see (it should be set to public).

https://github.com/chaseschlachter/musicmaker/blob/main/index.ejs

Comment: You need to pass 'Artists' in your view render   res.render('artists/index', Artists ) as you are using Artists in view file. Better first check variable before use.